How to record the inference trace of a Keras model / How to evaluate a keras model step by step?
my work requires me to record the intermediate states of a Keras model. As shown below, I need to extract the states between layers. I wonder if Keras comes with something that I can use to dump this?
Alternatively, I think this can also be done by manually evaluating the network step by step. I would manually pull out the dense layers and evaluate them one by one. But I'm not sure how to do that as all the examples I can find predicts using the keras model as a whole.
Thanks!

